# How to check if child of element exists

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
{
  student: {
    firstName: 'Seif',
    lastName: 'Ali',
    countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
    nationalId: '21106250100531',
    gender: 'MALE',
    dateOfBirth: '2011-06-25',
    errors: ['invalid nationalId '],
  },
  firstGuardian: {
    firstName: 'Ali',
    lastName: 'Ahmed',
    phoneNumber: '0101660666',
    email: 'jojo@gmail.com',
    countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
    nationalId: '28108090100531',
    gender: 'MALE',
    dateOfBirth: '1981-08-09',
    errors: ['invalid phone Number '],
  },
  secondGuardian: {
    firstName: 'Aya',
    lastName: 'Adel',
    phoneNumber: '01016605555',
    email: 'aya@gmail.com',
    countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
    nationalId: '29710250103561',
    gender: 'FEMALE',
    dateOfBirth: '1997-10-25',
  },
};
```

I expect to be like this

```
{
    student: {
        firstName: 'Seif',
        lastName: 'Ali',
        countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
        nationalId: '21106250100531',
        gender: 'MALE',
        dateOfBirth: '2011-06-25',
    },
    firstGuardian: {
        firstName: 'Ali',
        lastName: 'Ahmed',
        phoneNumber: '0101660666',
        email: 'jojo@gmail.com',
        countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
        nationalId: '28108090100531',
        gender: 'MALE',
        dateOfBirth: '1981-08-09',
    },
    secondGuardian: {
        firstName: 'Aya',
        lastName: 'Adel',
        phoneNumber: '01016605555',
        email: 'aya@gmail.com',
        countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
        nationalId: '29710250103561',
        gender: 'FEMALE',
        dateOfBirth: '1997-10-25'
    },
    errors :  ['invalid nationalId ' ,'invalid phone Number ']
}
```

Comment: I just hope those are dummy data :)

Comment: yes it is a dummy data

Comment: I would suggest the use of example domains for dummy data. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for in` loop to iterate over the data, then destructure the `errors` from the nested objects and concatenate all the destructured errors together to get your desired results.

Try this

```js
let data = {
  student: {
    firstName: 'Seif',
    lastName: 'Ali',
    countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
    nationalId: '21106250100531',
    gender: 'MALE',
    dateOfBirth: '2011-06-25',
    errors: ['invalid nationalId '],
  },
  firstGuardian: {
    firstName: 'Ali',
    lastName: 'Ahmed',
    phoneNumber: '0101660666',
    email: 'jojo@gmail.com',
    countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
    nationalId: '28108090100531',
    gender: 'MALE',
    dateOfBirth: '1981-08-09',
    errors: ['invalid phone Number '],
  },
  secondGuardian: {
    firstName: 'Aya',
    lastName: 'Adel',
    phoneNumber: '01016605555',
    email: 'aya@gmail.com',
    countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
    nationalId: '29710250103561',
    gender: 'FEMALE',
    dateOfBirth: '1997-10-25',
  },
};

let result = {errors: []};

for (let key in data) {
    let {errors, ...rest} = data[key];
    result[key]   = {...rest};
    result.errors = result.errors.concat(errors ?? []);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```js
let obj = {
    student: {
        firstName: 'Seif',
        lastName: 'Ali',
        countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
        nationalId: '21106250100531',
        gender: 'MALE',
        dateOfBirth: '2011-06-25',
        errors: ['invalid nationalId '],
    },
    firstGuardian: {
        firstName: 'Ali',
        lastName: 'Ahmed',
        phoneNumber: '0101660666',
        email: 'jojo@gmail.com',
        countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
        nationalId: '28108090100531',
        gender: 'MALE',
        dateOfBirth: '1981-08-09',
        errors: ['invalid phone Number '],
    },
    secondGuardian: {
        firstName: 'Aya',
        lastName: 'Adel',
        phoneNumber: '01016605555',
        email: 'aya@gmail.com',
        countryOfCitizenship: 'EG',
        nationalId: '29710250103561',
        gender: 'FEMALE',
        dateOfBirth: '1997-10-25',
    },
};
let res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    acc[key] ??= {...val};
    delete acc[key].errors;
    return acc;
}, {});
res.errors = Object.values(obj).flatMap(ele => ele.errors).filter(ele => !!ele);
console.log(res);
```